# Python3 Endpoint Mismatch on Gemini Sandbox API

Tags: python-3.x, hmac, algorithmic-trading, hashlib

I'm building an algorithmic trading application in Python3 for currency trading.  I'm trying to call the Gemini Exchange Sandbox API in Python3 to get current balances.  Each time I send my post request, I get back an error as follows:

```
{
 "result":"error",
 "reason":"EndpointMisatch",
 "message":"EndpointMisatch"
}
```

In response to this, I altered my endpoint to the production url of 'https://api.gemini.com/v1/balances' and that results in an InvalidSignature error.

I have deleted my API from the sandbox and created a new one ensuring I have fund manager and trader access both with and without heartbeats to no avail. The documentation is here: https://docs.sandbox.gemini.com/rest-api/?python#error-codes

Here is my function:
    import requests 
    import json
    import time
    import base64
    import hmac
    import hashlib

```
def checkBalance(self):
    '''
        function calls private gemini method
        to return account balances.  Update with
        production or sandbox keys/secrets depending on 
        environment running.
    '''
    #set increment for unique session
    nonce = int(round(time.time()*1000))

    #sandbox api endpoint
    url = 'https://api.sandbox.gemini.com/v1/balances'

    #build the dict payload object
    payload = {
        'request':'v1/balances',
        'nonce': nonce
    }

    #endcode payload as a json object for hashing
    payload = str.encode(json.dumps(payload))

    #base64 encode the payload
    b64 = base64.b64encode(payload)

    #create the signature using sandbox secret and encoded payload in sha384 hash
    signature = hmac.new(str.encode(self.s_secret), b64, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()

    #build headers as required for contacting api endpoint
    headers = {
        'Content-Type':'text/plain',
        'X-GEMINI-APIKEY': self.s_key,
        'X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD': b64,
        'X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE': signature
    }

    #retrieve data from POST request as response
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)

    #return text of response
    return response.text
```

I'm new to working with the b64, hmac and hashlib libraries.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much testing, I found the problem.  My payload data dictionary had the endpoint listed as 'v1/balances' instead of '/v1/balances'.  My new payload data looks like this (created a function to deal with nonce):

```
payload = dict(request = '/v1/balances', nonce = str(self.nonce()))
```

When I updated the payload with this info and posted the data, my sandbox response appears as follow:

```
[{
    'type': 'exchange', 
    'currency': 'BTC', 
    'amount': '1000', 
    'available': '1000', 
    'availableForWithdrawal': '1000'
 }, 
 {
    'type': 'exchange', 
    'currency': 'USD', 
    'amount': '100000.00', 
    'available': '100000.00', 
    'availableForWithdrawal': '100000.00'
 }, 
 {
    'type': 'exchange', 
    'currency': 'ETH', 
    'amount': '20000', 
    'available': '20000', 
    'availableForWithdrawal': '20000'
}]
```